# Palabras sobreesdrújulas: ¿cuándo se escriben con tilde?

Tags: acentuación

Todas las palabras esdrújulas llevan tilde. Había oido que las sobreesdrújulas también lo llevan, pero encontré "exactamente" y otros adverbios escritos sin acento.

¿Cuál es exactamente la regla de acentuación para sobreesdrújulas?

Comment: _"Los adverbios terminados en -mente son las únicas palabras en español que poseen dos acentos prosódicos: el que proviene del adjetivo del cual derivan y el de la terminación –mente, por eso no se pueden clasificar en una única categoría según las reglas de acentuación ortográfica."_ (http://www.elcastellano.org/consultas.php?Tag=prosodia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las palabras sobresdrújulas como regla general llevan tilde  en la trasantepenúltima sílaba, sean compuestas o no.

La única excepción son adverbios creados a partir de un adjetivo sin tilde más el sufijo -*mente*.

Ejemplos:

- Atrapa + me + lo --> Atrápamelo --> Lleva tilde porque contado por el final la sílaba tónica es la cuarta.
- Difícil + mente -->  Difícilmente --> Lleva tilde porque contado por el final la sílaba tónica es la cuarta.
- Evidente + mente --> Evidentemente --> Excepción a la regla porque deriva de un adjetivo sin tilde.

Comment: Atrápamelo, bésamelo, chúpamelo, acaríciamelo, pónmelo, sácamelo, mójamelo, sécamelo, .... alguien tendría que avisarle a los no hispanoparlantes acerca del riesgo de utilizar este tipo de palabras

Comment: Ya estamos ... Siempre pensando en lo mismo ... :)

Comment: No siempre. Hay que dejar algunas horas para dormir. Ahora, mejor no hablar de qué cosas se sueñan en ese lapso ...

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro exactamente de la regla, pero se omite el tilde cuando se trata de palabras compuestas, como con prefijos o sufijos.